# How to change tooltip direction in Chart.js (2.9.4)?

Tags: chart.js

I have a stacked bar chart in Chart.js 2.9.4.

On hovering, the tooltip's tip is positioned at the top-center of each bar, but the tooltip itself is rendered to the right and blocks the view of other bars.

[image]

I'd like to draw the tooltip **above** the bar. Is there a way to do this?

[See the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kennysong/sxgom7qt/9/).

---

(Here's the raw code as required by StackOverflow)

```js
// Get the past 14 days for the x-axis
var allDates = [
    moment('2021-04-04T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-05T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-06T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-07T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-08T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-09T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-10T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-11T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-12T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-13T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-14T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-15T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-16T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-17T00:00:00'),
    moment('2021-04-18T00:00:00'),
];

// Simulated distribution per day
var distributionPerDay = [
  [0.13, 0.05, 0.12, 0.07, 0.11, 0.14, 0.22, 0.06, 0.  , 0.1 ],
  [0.1 , 0.08, 0.1 , 0.09, 0.13, 0.12, 0.18, 0.11, 0.03, 0.06],
  [0.08, 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.09, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.2 , 0.09, 0.03, 0.06],
  [0.09, 0.09, 0.12, 0.07, 0.13, 0.12, 0.15, 0.14, 0.01, 0.08],
  [0.05, 0.05, 0.16, 0.13, 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.11, 0.1 ],
  [0.05, 0.05, 0.16, 0.13, 0.1 , 0.13, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.07, 0.09],
  [0.08, 0.05, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.13, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.13, 0.08, 0.06],
  [0.1 , 0.08, 0.13, 0.07, 0.1 , 0.13, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.05, 0.09],
  [0.08, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.08, 0.13, 0.1 , 0.13, 0.07, 0.07, 0.12],
  [0.12, 0.08, 0.1 , 0.04, 0.1 , 0.14, 0.11, 0.12, 0.09, 0.1 ],
  [0.08, 0.06, 0.16, 0.07, 0.07, 0.19, 0.07, 0.14, 0.11, 0.05],
  [0.08, 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.09, 0.1 , 0.16, 0.12, 0.12, 0.06, 0.07],
  [0.12, 0.09, 0.14, 0.04, 0.16, 0.08, 0.12, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.03],
  [0.09, 0.16, 0.1 , 0.07, 0.13, 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.11, 0.08, 0.06],
  [0.13, 0.12, 0.13, 0.04, 0.15, 0.11, 0.06, 0.12, 0.06, 0.08]
]

// Define colors for each bar (10 bars)
var colors = ['#9e0142', '#d53e4f', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#e6f598', '#abdda4', '#66c2a5', '#3288bd', '#5e4fa2'];  // cb-Spectral

// Convert distribution into Chart.js datasets
var classNames = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var datasets = [];
classNames.forEach(function(className, i) {
  // Gather the data {x: date, y: percentage} for this class
  var data = [];
  distributionPerDay.forEach(function(dist, j) {
    data.push({x: allDates[j], y: dist[i]});
  });

  // Add data and config to the datasets array
  datasets.push({
    label: className,
    data: data,
    backgroundColor: colors[i],
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: 'black',
    hoverBorderWidth: 1,  // Show a 1px black border on hover
    borderSkipped: false,  // Draw all four borders around the bar
    minBarLength: 1  // So even a bar for 0 has 1px height
  });
});

var myChart = new Chart('my-chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: { datasets: datasets },
  options: {
    hover: {
      mode: 'dataset',  // Highlight an entire row on hover
      animationDuration: 0  // Otherwise there is flickering when sliding over the bars quickly
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'nearest',  // Only show tooltip data of one bar on hover
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
        },
        offset: true,  // Otherwise the left and right bars are cut off
        ticks: { source: 'data' }  // Use one tick per point in allDates
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 1.0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `yAlign: 'bottom'` in tooltip options, [see the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/152hrncp/)

[image]

---

Relevant part of the code:

```
var myChart = new Chart('my-chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: { datasets: datasets },
  options: {
    hover: {
      mode: 'dataset',  
      animationDuration: 0
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      yAlign: 'bottom' //use this to control the placement of the tooltip relative to its point
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
        },
        offset: true,
        ticks: { source: 'data' }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 1.0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

It isn't mentioned in the official documentation, but works for Chart.js 2.9.4
(you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/171a7e3a7a23b1d4a9d37ed2b2495698969b79d5/src/core/core.tooltip.js#L424) where that option is used to override the automatic alignment calculation based on tooltip and chart size)

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks! I wonder why this is not documented....